# How do I write a random walk with drift ARIMA?

Tags: forecasting, arima, model, stochastic-processes, function

I modeled oil prices and got the following coeffecients for my arima model with drift.[image]

Is this the right way of writing the model?
[image]

Comment: I have changed my question new.